# iOS touch : fast and slow touch move

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to make touch mouse using iPhone. I want know how to make different slow move and fast move. I want make the cursor on PC move far when I move touch fast on iPhone. Currently, mine move same distance(pixels) for both slow and fast. Some velocity is required. Is there any simple idea or proper framework?

Comment: use touches methods . that is easy way to get touch events and very fast responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're already using a pan gesture recognizer, or at least know how to hook one up for this.  If you do that, you can get velocity this way:

```
- (void) handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan {
    CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"Horizontal velocity: %f", velocity.x);
    NSLog(@"Vertical velocity: %f", velocity.y);
}
```

Velocity is returned as a CGPoint where the `x` value represents horizontal velocity and the `y` value represents vertical velocity.  The further the value is from 0, the faster it is.

Comment: I actually used touch began/move/end to get current x, y coordination and their movement incremental. How can I get new coordination (x, y) from/with velocity.x, y in PanGesture? There would be some function between coordination and velocity.

Comment: Oh. velocity.x & y seems to be the incremental value for movement. It is really too fast if I use those value without any calculation.thanks

Comment: You can check but I'm pretty sure it's delivered in pixels per second. You can use another method if you prefer.

Comment: I used your suggestion with some simple weight. And Now perfectly works for me. Thanks Logan